# How do I write for loop equivalent in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Below code snippet trying to add 100 users then prints in console . But I require for loop equivalent in Java 8 using Instream.range(1,100) ....

```
public class UsersMain {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

     List<Users>  users =new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
            users.add(new Users());
        }
  }
}
```

Users Class with Constructor:

```
public class Users  {
    public Users() {
    }
}
```

Comment: how about this :`List<Users>  users = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> new Users()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2):

```
  List<Users> users = IntStream.range(0, 100)
                     .mapToObj(i -> new Users()) 
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use any `range()` or `rangeClosed()` methods, the key difference between both are:

> `range()` method generates a stream of numbers starting from start value
>   but stops before reaching the end value, i.e start value is inclusive
>   and end value is exclusive. Example: `IntStream.range(1,5)` generates a
>   stream of ‘1,2,3,4’ of type int.
>
> `rangeClosed()` method generates a stream of numbers starting from start
>   value and stops after generating the end value, i.e start value is
>   inclusive and end value is also inclusive. Example:
>   `LongStream.rangeClosed(1,5)` generates a stream of ‘1,2,3,4,5’ of type
>   long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rangeClosed` amd `mapToObj` as:

```
List<Users> users = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100) // rangeClosed for '<='
        .mapToObj(i -> new Users()) // would prefer at least an 'index' attribute to distinguish these objects
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collectin to a list
```

***Note***: Though the above code is same as your for loop, yet if you're trying to add 100 users specifically you must use `range` instead of `rangeClosed`.

Comment: @OleV.V. same as the code in the question. <= MohammedAneesA

Comment: His words and code is contradictory! :D He has written to add only 100 Users!

Comment: @MohamedAneesA Added a note there in the answer.